# Select all columns from a table where each user_id is different

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating an activity feed displaying my users activity that is limited to the last 5 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM activity ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 5
```

The problem is I don't want the activity feed to be cluttered by the same user at any point so I want to retrieve the last 5 results where the user_id's are different from each other.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch last 5 `DISTINCT` records?

Comment: have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no multiple `max(date)` for each user, you could use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   activity
WHERE  (user_id, `date`) IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT   user_id, max(`date`)
    FROM     activity
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY max(`date`) DESC
    LIMIT 5) s
  )
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c220c/5).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`SELECT user_id, MAX(date) FROM activity GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it would be an easy thing using a query like

```
SELECT DISTINCT activity.user_id,activity.* order by date DESC limit 5
```

Mysql Distinct reference : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/distinct-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

It can help you.

```
SELECT * FROM activity GROUP BY user ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, 
SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM activity ORDER BY date desc LIMIT 5